# Source Code Blender

Tags: interface, development

Can someone tell me in which part of the source code is this section of tabs?
I have searched a lot but in fact I need help because it is too long both in lines of code, as in number of files, and it would help me a lot to know where this is in the short term, to be able to continue learning about blender and how it is programmed

[image: Tabs section]
[image: when you click on modify source code]

Comment: I don't think the properties header is exposed to python. I'm pretty sure that this part of the UI is written in C. If that doesn't matter, you can start here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender

Comment: @brockmann yes, UI is in C/C++,and not work with blender python api, i know C/C++ mid level, and I would like to try a couple of ideas, but I need to get to that part of the code and nobody says anything to me.

Comment: I've already asked at blender.org but he ignored me, I guess he has no value wanting to learn about the blender code or just consider They have some things to do, and that means that the community management that shares and helps, and why ask here, there are some like Mike Pan who are here, and that is an option to contact him, and that some things in a sporadic way, I do not pretend to give me 100% of your time, just a few questions from time to time

Comment: I quickly searched for it and I think the source code of the *properties area* is located in `.../source/blender/editors/space_buttons/` and the header code is in `space_buttons.c`. Better try the official [IRC channel](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community:Chat) for development questions. Also this [old diagram](https://www.blender.org/bf/codelayout.jpg) from the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Blender_Source/Files_Structure) should help diving into it. Good luck!

Comment: @brockmann Thank you very much, this is very helpful, I'm a little closer to the goal, I'll try to do the search where you indicate me, and I'll also ask in the IRC chat, as soon as I have an answer, I'll share it again with everyone here, thanks again, Assalamu Alaykum

**I had been looking at** blender-master-2.78 / source / blender / editors / interface /

Comment: @Mike Pan can you help me please, you are designare in this project
https://developer.blender.org/project/view/12/